# Can't access lexical definition of response before initialization within a React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to make the home page send one API call on load and display all results on screen. It seems to send the call and receive response fine, although despite receiving the response from the server it can't pass the contents of the payload within the code, which is a JSON.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const localUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
        if (localUser) {
            const foundUser = localUser;
            setUser(foundUser);
        } else {
            const newUser = uuidv1();
            localStorage.setItem(newUser, user);
            setUser(newUser);
        }
        console.log(user);
        async function fetchPosts() {
            try {
                let tempPosts = [];
                const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response.payload.forEach(object => tempPosts.push(object.post)))
                    .then(setPosts((posts) => [tempPosts]));
                console.log(posts);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }

        fetchPosts();

    }, [user, posts]);
```

Somehow React is trying to access the response without the declaration and I have no idea how, which in result stops the function from executing.

Comment: I didn't understand your question but I noticed that you are always updating `user` with `setUser` and also using `user` as a dependency for the effect, assuming that `user` is a result of a `useState` that's not shown in this code snippet, wouldn't that produce an infinite loop of the effect?

Comment: @MauroAguilar yes that's correct, solved another issue of mine, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts')
                       .then(response => response.json())
```

You're combining two paradigms - asynchronous programming using `Promise`s and callbacks with `then`, and asynchronous programming using `async`/`await`. You'll usually want to pick one or the other for use in a single function, and you definitely cannot combine them in a single line (or at least, not like this).

If you want to use `async` (and I would recommend this approach), you'll probably want something like this:

```js
async function fetchPosts() {
    let tempPosts = [];
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/posts');
    const data = await response.json();
    data.payload.forEach(object => tempPosts.push(object.post))
    
    return tempPosts;
}
```

I don't know what `data` looks like, so you may have to play with the 4th line of the function, but hopefully you get the gist. You'll probably want to define this function outside of your component, and certainly not within the `useEffect` hook.

An example of how you could use this to fetch posts on the first render of your component is

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchPosts().then(data => setPosts(data));
}, []);
```

assuming you have a relevant `useState` hook.

Comment: `setPosts(fetchPosts());` will not work because `fetchPosts` will still return a Promise.